# Write date in various formats

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming, so my problems might have very simple solutions. I need to write a code that will convert date from format such as 6,17,2016 to June 17, 2016.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
def date_it(month, day, year):

    months={"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"}

    for month in months:

        print (month[5] +" "+str(day)+", "+str(year))
```

This returns June 17, 2016. However, I don't want it to return just June. I want it to be able to convert whatever inputed month e.g(8) into the corresponding month(August).
Please help.

Comment: Just a head's up, "months" is a set. Sets are like lists but HAVE NO ORDER. You can't really extract any useful information from that set. Either use square brackets for a list, normal brackets for a tuple, or (if you want) make it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("6,17,2016", '%m,%d,%Y').strftime('%B %d %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

print (str(months[month-1] )  +" "+ str(day) +", "+ str(year))